# How to apply a function to a three dimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, apply

I have a three dimensional array containing time (in years), latitude, and longitude. I would like to count the number of zeros a given coordinate has over the entire timescale by using the apply function. I have written a function to count the number of zeros when I specify a latitude and longitude, but I cannot seem to apply this function over the entire array. My code:

```
#to sum zeros at a given lat and lon across all years combined
sum.zero <- function(x, lat, lon) {
  sum(is.zero(x[,lat,lon]))
  
}

#to test for zero 
is.zero <- function(x) {
  x == 0 


}
```

```
 numberofzeros <- apply(data, c(2,3), sum.zero)

 Error in x[, lat, lon] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Comment: Could you provide some minimal example data to use with your code? This would help us reproduce the issue.

Comment: You're applying `sum.zero` to two-dimensional slices of your three-dimensional array. But then `sum.zero` assumes that `x` has three dimensions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I am not sure how to make example data in the exact format I have but I am using an array created from Land Use Harmonisation 2 Dataset which is in netcdf4 format. https://daac.ornl.gov/VEGETATION/guides/LUH2_GCB2019.html

Comment: @dash2 I've tried amending the code to 
`numberofzeros <- apply(data, c(1,2,3), sum.zero)`
but the same error occurs

Comment: Sounds like you've changed the wrong thing. You want to apply `sum.zero` to two-dimensional slices of your array. But you don't want it to assume that `x` has three dimensions. Another point: you're assuming that `sum.zero` will be called with 3 arguments. But `apply` just calls `sum.zero` with one argument, the slice of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```r
# test data
data <- array(c(1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0), dim = c(2,2,2))
apply(data, c(2,3), function (x) sum(x==0))
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    0
[2,]    2    1
```